# Sync python threads, share their states and close all threads in one time

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, multiprocessing

My project is an API for some hardware mechanics. User can just send commands via socket and receive responses from hardware.
For this purpose I use two sockets. One is for receiving responses (let's name it `RTD` and one for sending commands (`CMDS`).

I have 3 classes. `ReceiverRTD`, `API` and `Controller`.

`ReceiverRTD` is an inherited from `threading.Thread` class. It connects to the `RTD` socket and receives data-packages with high frequency. Class stores this data into its class field and overwrites it every time new package arrives.

`API` - is the main class, runs in main thread. User can create it's own script (where `API` class object will be created) and call `API` methods taking into account the logic of his script.

`Controller` - is the commands-sending class. It connects to `CMDS` socket and has a couple of methods for package sending. It also runs in main thread and its methods is going to be called from `API`.

It turns out that `API` is an user interface. `Controller` is socket and hardware interface. `ReceiverRTD` is a support class, providing some data for `API` logic.

So, the logic is described below (sorry, stackoverflow had a server error when i was writing this question, so, diagram is posted manually, on imgur): https://imgur.com/a/6kzmshI

So, if exception happens in `Controller` or `API` (all in main thread) I can shutdown `ReceiverRTD` and finish the program correctly.
Just setup some logic in `ReceiverRTD` receiving loop with `while threading.main_thread().is_alive():` and call `sys.exit` in main thread.

But if exception happens in `ReceiverRTD`, I can't just call sys.exit(), because `ReceiverRTD` is a child thread and calling `sys.exit()` will close this thread only, when i need to close the whole program, like in the previous case. And, also, it is not possible to create an endless loop in the `API` or `Controller` to check the `ReceiverRTD` status, because user defines his own script logic in main thread too and can lock the main thread for a along time.

I've found, that I can use `os._exit()` and it kills the whole process (which is what i actually wanted). But, this is not the best practise, as i understood from stackoverflow previous questions. Also, it's a bit dirty to use it, bc it's a "private" method. And if we call this method, it would not be possible to use any `KeyBoardInterrupt` custom handlers or any pre-exit methods.

So, how can I sync threads in both directions and actually "terminate" the program correctly?

***P.S. I do not attach the code, because this is mostly the architectural question.***

Comment: Why would you ever want to inherit from `Thread`? Is your class an in-place replacement for `Thread`? No, it isn't. In other words, you break [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which is one of [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). Just use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Secondly, don't ever use `sys.exit` nor `os._exit`. Killing a process is insanely bad idea, makes your code almost unsuable. Killing a thread is also bad, makes it hard to move the code to other concurrency models like threadpool or async. Handle an exception in thread either by just simply logging it, or notifying another thread through a queue. Separate threads should be monitored anyway. Thread safe queues: that's the answer to most thread synchronization issues.

Comment: @freakish i need to terminate process, because user will use my API to manipulate robot and user can create a situation, where robot will crash something. In API I have some functions, which will be used by user like an check-functions (like checking robot speed and position). So, if robot going to break limits, we need to stop him. Yes, we will send stop command, but we don't terminate user's script, which will cause sending another commands, defined in the script, so robot can start moving incorrectly (because we didn't execute some of the functions earlier).Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: @freakish thank you for the SOLID hint, I will refactor the code

Comment: You don't *need to terminate process*. You need to prevent user from doing bad things. You need to gracefuly handle incorrect situations. Raise exceptions, close background threads if needed, close sockets, maybe do some logging. Shutdown everything correctly. Yes, this requires more code, but it is infinitely more useful than doing force kill.

Answer (score 0):

A few points you may find helpful:

1. It would have been more helpful if you had created a [sequence diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) for a typical user interaction in addition to the image you posted.
2. The `ReceiverRTD` thread needs to be a *daemon* thread so that if the main thread terminates due to an exception so will the `ReceiverRTD` thread and any other daemon threads. This also means that it no longer needs to pool the main thread to see if it is alive or not. I also think it more flexible not to have `ReceiverRTD` subclass `threading.Thread` and instead just use the *target* argument of the `Thread` initializer to execute the `ReceiverRTD` logic in a child thread. This way if you decided that you needed to run the logic in a child process instead, you do not need to modify your class hierarchy. Ultimately I will suggest below that you execute the receiving logic as a task submitted to a multithreading pool, which will make it pointless for `ReceiverRTD` to be a subclass of `Thread`.
3. You say "But if exception happens in ReceiverRTD, ...", but it's not clear whether `ReceiverRTD` is catching exceptions or not. Either way you seem to be saying that if an exception does occur in this thread you would like to terminate the running script even though an API call is not currently in progress. If so, then the following is one possible solution:

I would create a multithreading pool whose size is sufficient to run all of your threads. The threads created for such a pool are daemon threads so that if the main thread terminates, then any tasks being executed in the pool will terminate as well. For this you could use the `multithreading.pool.ThreadPool` class, which has the same interface as the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` multiprocessing pool class or the `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` class. By using a callback that gets invoked if a task submitted to the pool raises an exception, you do not need to handle unrecoverable exceptions in the receiving task. If you do catch such an exception, then it should be re-raised so that our callback is invoked:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

class API:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def do_something(self):
        """Perform some api call."""

        # Simulate doing something:
        import time

        time.sleep(5)

class ReceiverRTD:
    ...
    def start_receiving(self):
        """Start receiving from hardware via a socket."""

        # Simulate an eventual Exception raised in this task:
        import time

        time.sleep(1)
        raise Exception('oops')


def on_receiver_exception(exception):
    """Here if the receiving task raises an unrecoverable exception.
    This callback executes in a child thread so we need to
    kill the main process."""
    print('Exception in receiving task:', exception)

    import signal
    import os
    from multiprocessing import current_process

    os.kill(current_process().pid, signal.SIGTERM)

# Start receiving from hardware:
receiver = ReceiverRTD()
thread_pool = ThreadPool(1)  # We only need to run a single thread
thread_pool.apply_async(receiver.start_receiving, error_callback=on_receiver_exception)

# Presumably this module gets imported by the user's script, which then
# might execute something like the following:

api = API()
api.do_something()
# We never arrive here due to the exception in the receiver thread,
# which results in the termination of the script:
print('Done doing something')
...
```

Prints:

```
Exception in receiving task: oops
```

Comment: Thank you for such an expanded answer! I'll try to implement in my case. But will it affect speed in my API. ReceiverRTD is working with 500 hz rate and it need to fill up dataclass with 200 fields every 0.002 sec. Will threading pool affect the speed (as long as it's a thread "agregator" with additional logic)?

Comment: In addition. I don't see any difference between os._exit() and os.kill, except pre-exit handlers in the os.kill. We still abort all process with threads. But, looks like Pool is more correct decision.

Comment: If using a thread for `ReceiverRTD` was working for you, I would not think that the performance for this should be any different. This is just a way of detecting exceptions in that thread and terminating all threads without having to use private, undocumented methods. But you will need to try this and see.